# Could video_engine_timeout_detected be caused by this physical error?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, asus

I recently submitted a repair on my 4070ti gpu, and received back this image.

[image: 1]

I have no idea how this damaged occurred from resting in my PC. It is totally possible that it happened when I was taking it out to send in for repair. However, if I submit the repair cost, I want to be sure that it will actually fix the error I was having.

The error in question was `video_engine_timeout_detected` in the windows dmp logs when playing certain games. It seemed to be mostly sporadic, and it would crash back to the desktop when it did happen. It also seemed to randomly start occurring after 3 months of solid performance. From what I can tell googling, it sounds like the damage pictured on the connector would be more catastrophic with more bsod.

Any help is appreciated! I can provide more information as needed.

[Here are some pictures of the mobo pic connector it was plugged into.](https://imgur.com/a/bh157qH)

Comment: Not my specialty, but the little missing piece does not seem to reach the contacts, so perhaps is not the main problem.

Comment: The main thing I'd look for is in damage such as bent pins in the socket it came out of. If there is absolutely no damage then that notch is not necessarily the problem.

Comment: What would damage on the mobo look like for that pci slot?

Comment: there **is** actually a damaged contact, but not the one with the arrow: look all the way to the right, second from the Asus logo

Comment: @Yorik That is the PRSNT#2 pin and is intentionally shorter. Disconnect first when being removed and connect last when fitted, for hot-swap purposes.

Comment: that makes sense

Comment: I added photos of the PCI connection on my MOBO. It's hard to see, and I don't exactly know what I am looking for, but nothing looks damaged there.

Comment: @Yorik In case you're interested a better picture is at https://linustechtips.com/topic/1430037-broken-connector-on-gpu/ it's a very clean edge and no signs of damage so given the signal on the pin it is 100% intentional to give the motherboard a moment in time to disconnect signals and power when the card is being removed.

Comment: Yeah I am familiar with the hot-swap SATA connectors which also feature shorter pins, just didn't think about that.

Comment: @Brandon There's no obvious signs of anything. I assume the lighter patches in this image are just dust: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y83J3.png and I can't see any signs of force or damage or other troubles. There's no sign of anything out of place.

Comment: That is what I thought too. I will reply back to Asus report and set up a dispute. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the area of the problem I would expect the card to not work rather than to cause one specific part of the GPU chip itself to not work.

The notch is around the area of the TRST (a JTAG pin) and 3.3V pins in the area before the mechanical key. If any of those pins were actually damaged then I would expect the card to not work properly or to be weird after reboots or other issues. It's not in what I would expect to be a cause of intermittent faults. It's definitely not in an area that would normally be used to transfer data to or from the graphics card, it is essentially the "debug" section of the connector.

That it is at one of the 3.3V pins *might* mean that  the parts of the card that communicates with the motherboard could mean that under load (lots of communications) could cause issues if it's not connected properly. I'd expect it to be worse under gaming, not just some weirdness playing videos.

It *could* cause damage to any slot it is plugged into though. The sprung pins bend inwards slightly and could get caught on that notch rather than being pushed apart by a gentle tapering on the edge of the card. That *could* cause pins to short together and cause *oddness*.

See the pinout below. It looks to me that the damage is around pin 9 which is the third away from the mechanical key cutout.

You may be fine, but there is a slight risk in that notch.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reply. Do you think this is something that could have happened naturally with it sitting in the mobo? And is the pin actually damaged or is it the piece around the pin or does that matter?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to happen naturally, no. The material PCBs are made of is essentially fibreglass bonded together with epoxy resin and does not just "crumble" like that. It was either like that when it went in, or happened when being removed or shipped. It would be worth looking in the slot it came out of and inspecting for pins in that area that are bent or for debris or signs of the card being hit on the mechanical key.